# Signing and Encrypting file via GnuPG encryption

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I'm trying to sign and encrypt a text file via GnuPG encryption from a command line, but I'm getting the following error:

> sign+encrypt failed: No secret key

I know very little about GnuPG.  Our client gave me two OpenPGP keys with `.asc` file extensions.  He said file 1 is to sign the file and file 2 is to encrypt it.

File1.asc (to sign the file) looked something like this:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
Version: PGP 7.0.1

(key code here)
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: PGP 7.0.1

(key code here)
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

File2.asc (to encrypt) looked like this:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: PGP for Personal Privacy 5.0

(key code here)
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

I then tried running GnuPG via command line with something like the following:

```
gpg -r [file ame of encryption key] -s -u [password client gave for signing]  -o DirectoryWhereToOutputFile\sample.pgp -e DirectoryOfSampleFile\SampleFile
```

What do I need to change to get this to successfully sign and encrypt a file?

Answer (score 2):

GnuPG does not use keys as files, you have to import them before and use their key IDs.

```
gpg --import [private-key]
gpg --import [public-key]
```

Then, use the key ID of the public key (the one to encrypt for):

```
gpg -r [key-id] -s -o [output-file] -e [input-file]
```

If you don't know the IDs, use `gpg --list-keys` to obtain a list of all known keys. `gpg --list-secret-keys` will only show those you have the private key for, thus the one you can use for signing.

Answer (score 0):

In GnuPG, we generate keypair `gpg --gen-key`

- Encrypt using shared/imported public key - `gpg --recipient bob --encrypt filename`
- Decrypt using private key - `gpg --decrypt sharedMessage.asc`

Refer https://linux.101hacks.com/unix/gpg-command-examples/